# Can TCP socket bind to IPV6 address and connect to IPV4 peer?

Tags: sockets, tcp, ipv6, ipv4

Can I bind a TCP socket to a local IPV6 address, then connect it to peer IPV4 address? It seems impossible since an ip packet cannot include ipv4 (destination) address and ipv6 (source) address at the same time.

Comment: search "IPV6_V6ONLY" and set it to false. But you will be using IPv4 through an IPv6 socket interface. The connection will be IPv4 at both ends, not IPv4 to IPv6.

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are separate, incompatible protocols. The packet headers are very different, and the addressing is incompatible.

Comment: @user253751 Suppose I set IPV6_V6ONLY to false, what is the source ip the socket chooses to send the packet? It is not likely the ipv6 I bind it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I bind a TCP socket to a local IPV6 address, then connect it to peer IPV4 address?

No, the IP protocol must match for the connection to succeed. The `connect` call will simply fail, without even sending out any packets.